# Criteria subquery with not null

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria, detachedcriteria

I want to convert the following subquery to use hibernate subquery:

```
getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Employee where id in (select adminId from Department where adminId is not null)")
                   .list();
```

- Employee:

  ```
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "fk_department_id", nullable = true) 
  private Department department;
  ```
- Department:

  ```
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "fk_department_id")
  private Set<Employee> employees = new HashSet<Employee>(0);
  ```

Can anyone please provide me with an example of this convert, because i read some examples and i still cannot figure out how to do that.

Comment: BTW, i have a serious problem recently with adjusting any code block when posting a new question, i do as usual copy the code from my IDE or from text file and highlight the code then surround it with the code button, but it gets displayed badly.

Comment: That's because you're using tabs instead of spaces.

Comment: can you please tell me how was you able to reformat the code, so i can avoid such thing in future ?

Comment: In Eclipse I have settings to replace tabs with space, so when I copy my code I don't have to do nothing. In your case I've just removed the tabs and inserted spaces (while in lists you might need to type 8 spaces instead of 4.)

Comment: two more questions: 1- how to do such setting in eclipse ? 2- how did you removed the tabs and inserted spaces in my case, copied the code to your eclipse or did that manually ?

Comment: 1. `Preferences -> Java -> CodeStyle -> Formatter -> Edit -> Indentation -> Tab policy: Spaces only`. I've just done it manually - it was few lines, so it wasn't a big pain :-)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Employee.class, "e");
DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Departemt.class, "d");
dc.add(Restrictions.isNotNull("d.adminId");
dc.setProjection(Projections.property("d.adminId"));
c.add(Subqueries.propertyIn("e.id", dc));
```

The `setProjection` call makes the subquery return the `adminId` property only instead of the whole `Department` entity. The `Subqueries.propertyIn` creates a restriction: the property `id` of the searched employee must be `in` the set of results returned by the subquery.

Comment: it works fine, thanks, but can you please provide little explanation for the last two lines, i couldn't find doc for them.